# Build docker image from rhel6.5 image

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to build a python3-based container and install some requirements. But the build of python3 fails
Here my Dockerfile

```
FROM rhel6.5
ADD ./* /app/
WORKDIR /app/Python
CMD ["./configure"]
CMD ["make"]
CMD ["altinstall"]
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["python", "-m", "pip",  "install" , "-r" , "requirement.txt"]
```

After the build when i run

`sudo docker run myimage python -v`  gives 2.6 
when, I run the bash and trying to compile python again

```
sudo docker run -i myimage /bin/bash
./configure
```

I got

```
./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... linux
checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/app':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

Finally

```
yum install gcc
```

Also fails

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
Setting up Install Process
No package gcc available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely more steps to building python, here are the steps I recently used for Python 2.7.9 (I'm sure it is easy to adapt to 3.4):

- sudo yum groupinstall "Development tools"
- sudo yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel
- curl https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/Python-2.7.9.tgz -o ~/Python-2.7.9.tgz
- tar -xvf Python-2.7.9.tgz
- cd Python-2.7.9
- ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
- sudo vi /etc/ld.so.conf
- add /usr/local/lib on a new line and save.
- sudo /sbin/ldconfig
- make
- sudo make altinstall
- Remove Python-2.7.9 folder and Python-2.7.9.tgz archive

Because you are writing a `Dockerfile` you should:

- use `yum install -y` for installing dependencies
- Since you are `altinstalling` the python interpreter is available inside /usr/local/bin/python2.7  or python3.4 depending on the version you are installing.
- The whole purpose of `make altinstall` instead of `make install` is to make sure you don't break the system dependencies for the `python` executable.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a RHEL image; Red Hat Enterprise Linux is a commericial product and requires a paid subscription for access to updates.  You won't have any repositories configured unless you configure some subcriptions using `subscription-manager attach`.

If you are not currently a paid RHEL customer and you do not have a compelling reason to require RHEL, you could get access to effectively the same set of packages by using CentOS instead.

Also note that the current `fedora` and `ubuntu` images both have Python 3 available (as an installable package for Fedora, and included by default fo r Ubuntu).

Comment: For now i'm doing tests on REHL Google compute engine. But the target will to deploy the container on a REHL server. I will try to build the container from danzilla / centos6-python3-django  :) (https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/danzilla/centos6-python3-django/dockerfile/)

Comment: @saidomar The main idea behind Docker is to package up dependencies to the OS level so you don't have to worry about this. What this means is that you can run debian containers on a RHEL host and it will work just the same as if it was on a Debian host.

Comment: To ensure the customer support, it should be better to have all images rhel based.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Dockerfile` is wrong. You are using `CMD` instead of `RUN`. See the reference documentation about Dockerfile : https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/.

> The main purpose of a CMD is to provide defaults for an executing container.

Nothing in `CMD` is executed when building then ; it's just metadata, and only the last one is pick to be executed when running a container from the image.

If you use the following, docker will fail to build (but for a good reason).

```
FROM rhel6.5
ADD ./* /app/
WORKDIR /app/Python
RUN ./configure
RUN make
RUR altinstall
WORKDIR /app
RUN python -m pip install -r requirement.txt
```

You might want to add a step to install a compiler and the needed dependencies to be able to build python in your rhel. But I would follow the advice of @larsks and @Adrian Mouat.

Answer (score 0):

Deeply inspired from @Teodore's response and https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/danzilla/centos6-python3-django/dockerfile/

And adding

```
ADD ./* /app/
RUN pip3.4 install -r /app/requirement.txt
```

at the and of the file. Where requirement is all needed requirements for my project.

```
sudo docker run python3-redhat /usr/local/bin/python3.4 -c "import dja
ngo; print(django.get_version())"
```

give as expected 1.8.1.